# PHP regex ignores all symbols except letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to return true, if $str does not contains 'script+'.
It blocks only 'script', but not 'script+'...

How can i fix it?

```
if (!preg_match('/[\bscript+\b]/u', $str))
return true;
else
return false;
```

Comment: What are you trying to check exactly? Perhaps can we find a better solution if you explain what is your goal (with good examples)

Comment: You can also use `strpos()`. If it returns `false` then the string does not contain it, otherwise it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a character class, which matches just a single character. You should remove it. And there is no point in using `\b` after `+`, as `+` is not a word. You should remove it too. And then escape the `+` outside the character class, as it is a meta-character in regex.

And certainly, you can replace the `if-else` block there, with single `return` statement like so:

```
return !preg_match('/\bscript\+/u', $str)
```

Comment: While the last `\b` may be unnecessary, removing the first `\b` definitely changes the meaning.